# which branches of a mongodb $or query were satisfied to include a document in the set returned?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Say I have a mongo $or query, something like `{ $or: [query1, query2, ... queryN] }`, where each embedded query could be complex. Upon executing the query, a set of documents matching one or more of the embedded queries is returned. I would like to know which of the N embedded queries was satisfied for each document in the returned set, perhaps by adding a new field that I specify, eg. `marks`, into each returned document that would hold a list of the indexes of whichever of the queries was satisfied. I need this information to indicate how each document was identified in my application's interface.

I realize I could inspect the set once it is returned and determine the queries that were satisfied, but these queries could be arbitrarily complex and expensive to inspect - besides, this must have already been done inside mongo itself while doing the search.

I also realize I could run each of the N queries sequentially and then mark and merge the results into a growing set, but I want to save that overhead by running a single query instead of N queries.

And I realize that Mongo will certainly stop once the first satisfying query is found for each document, so I may not be able to get the complete set, but then I would at least like some assurance that the queries are executed in a certain order, say 1...N, and each document could be marked with its first satisfying index.

Does anyone know if there's a mechanism in Mongo that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.

Use `$addFields` to add a new field for each query.

You could either `$match` first, and then add the fields, or add the fields first and on the added fields.